# Typescript version problem while updating Angular 8 to Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Angular 9 support typescript >=3.6 and <3.8. But while updating angular 8 to 9 the cli is installing ts 3.8 which is not supported by angular 9 itself.
[image]

Comment: It is solved. It's needed to update with --force flag. Then the typescript version need to be updated manually to any version >=3.6 and <3.6. As for example : npm install --save typescript@3.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to version 9 requires very specific actions. The good news is they are all documented here.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17297

**Summary**

Upgrade to latest version of 8 first. Then to  9. Using the  --force option fixes your issue.

Comment: I have updated to latest version of angular 8 as per the update steps stated in update documentation. Now using --force

Comment: Ok now go to 9 and use --force option